# In Linq-to-Nhibernate, has anyone managed to use .Contains in a where clause and also NHibernate.Linq.ToFuture() in the same query? (NH 3.x)

Tags: linq-to-nhibernate, nhibernate-3

I always get a "System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException" that says "The given key was not present in the dictionary" whenever I try to use .Contains and the ToFuture() method in one query.

Imagine the DBObject contains a bunch of properties with one of them being an integer "ID"

```
List<int> test = new List<int>();
        test.Add(1557);
        test.Add(1558);
        test.Add(1559);

        IEnumerable<DBObject> test2 = getLinqQuerySomehow<DBObject>().Where(x => test.Contains(x.ID)).ToFuture();
        List<DBObject> results = test2.ToList();
```

Can anyone reproduce this? Does anyone know of another way besides contains() to make Linq-to-Nhibernate use the SQL IN clause for the ints in my test list while also using ToFuture()?

Stacktrace:

> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
>   at NHibernate.Param.NamedParameterSpecification.SetEffectiveType(QueryParameters queryParameters) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Param\NamedParameterSpecification.cs:line 70
>   at NHibernate.Param.ParametersBackTrackExtensions.ResetEffectiveExpectedType(IEnumerable`1 parameterSpecs, QueryParameters queryParameters) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Param\ParametersBackTrackExtensions.cs:line 48
>   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Loader.QueryLoader.ResetEffectiveExpectedType(IEnumerable`1 parameterSpecs, QueryParameters queryParameters) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\Loader\QueryLoader.cs:line 428
>   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.CreateSqlCommand(QueryParameters queryParameters, ISessionImplementor session) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 1649
>   at NHibernate.Impl.MultiQueryImpl.AggregateQueriesInformation() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\MultiQueryImpl.cs:line 641
>   at NHibernate.Impl.MultiQueryImpl.get_Parameters() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\MultiQueryImpl.cs:line 774
>   at NHibernate.Impl.MultiQueryImpl.CreateCombinedQueryParameters() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\MultiQueryImpl.cs:line 754
>    at NHibernate.Impl.MultiQueryImpl.List() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\MultiQueryImpl.cs:line 400
>    at NHibernate.Impl.FutureQueryBatch.GetResultsFrom(IMultiQuery multiApproach) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\FutureQueryBatch.cs:line 24
>    at NHibernate.Impl.FutureBatch`2.GetResults() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\FutureBatch.cs:line 73
>   at NHibernate.Impl.FutureBatch`2.get_Results() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\FutureBatch.cs:line 29
>   at NHibernate.Impl.FutureBatch`2.GetCurrentResult[TResult](Int32 currentIndex) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\FutureBatch.cs:line 79
>   at NHibernate.Impl.FutureBatch`2.c__DisplayClass4`1.b__3() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\FutureBatch.cs:line 63
>   at NHibernate.Impl.DelayedEnumerator`1.d__0.MoveNext() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\DelayedEnumerator.cs:line 26
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>   at TestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() in C:\checkout\Library Projects\BaseSystemCore\TestProject1\UnitTest1.cs:line 94

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. I found it in the Nhibernate issue tracker:

https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2897

Edit: Should be fixed in NH 4.0.

Comment: its still broken in 3.3. You can use contains and tofuture if the .contains searches through a collection of 1. Don't be fooled, it doesn't work for collections of more than one.